# How to integrate external google login/signup on Web forms asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, google-signin

I saw the other post here that googleauth does not work on Web forms in ASP.NET, it only works on MVC project, if it does not work are there any options? Thanks! this is our first time creating external login

Comment: " saw the other post here that googleauth does not work on Web forms in ASP.NET" - correct, there is no simple or built-in way to support OIDC authentication in ASP.NET WebForms. It **is** still possible to implement but you'll need to build the entire OIDC infrastructure yourself (which you shouldn't do). Given that ASP.NET WebForms is now completely obsolete and irrelevant in 2021 (e.g. it isn't supported by .NET Core, .NET 5, etc, it generates horrible HTML and seems to think IE6 is more capable than Google Chrome you really need to migrate away asap).

Comment: Which 'other post here' are you referring to?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/login-with-google-account-api-in-asp-net-and-get-google-plus-profile-details-in-c-sharp